Using extern with multiple static variables at different scopes with same identifier
I was reading the following question posted here #67418392
I was curious regarding the behavior if the first two declarations of x were made with static (internal linkage at file scope and no linkage at block scope) as follows:
#include <stdio.h>

static int x = 50;

int main() {
    static int x = 10;

    {  
         extern int x;
         printf("inner block: %d\n", x);

    }

    printf("outer block: %d\n", x);
    return 0;

}

However GCC gives the following error (which goes away if the second static int x=10; is commented out). Why is this?
<source>:10:18: error: variable previously declared 'static' redeclared 'extern'
10 |       extern int x;
   |                  ^

There is no compiler error from clang or msvc. Why is that?
In the above code, when you have the statement extern int x; Shouldn't it use the declaration in the previous block such that it would print the following when run (this is what I was expecting)
inner block: 10
outer block: 10

Or is it because the static variable within the block (main function) has no linkage so it uses the one at file scope?
When compiling with clang it shows this instead:
inner block: 50
outer block: 10

From #67418392 one of the answers quote the C standard:

§6.2.2p4 of the C standard:
For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which a prior declaration
of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies
internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the
later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior
declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior
declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external
linkage.

In the example code is it that the static variable at file scope is not visible where extern int x; is declared as it is shadowed by the static definition in the main function (which has no linkage) and therefore according to the standard the extern declaration takes on external linkage. In this case we have x with external and internal linkage and therefore undefined behavior?

@Someprogrammerdude In the example code the variable was declared (not defined/redefined) using extern to my understanding. Also the static class storage specifier indicates internal linkage at file scope so the subsequent extern at blockscope should be internal linkage as well...?

I don't like the tentative conclusion I'm coming to, but I think both compilers are buggy.  GCC shouldn't be complaining because of the quoted passage from the standard.  The extern int x; is an identifier declared with the storage class extern in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible (that being the static int x = 10;), and the prior declaration specifies internal linkage, so the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. [continued 1…]

[…continuation 1…]  That seems to mean GCC should not complain (extern int x; seems to be a legitimate redeclaration of static int x = 10;.  It also means Clang should not print 50; it should print 10 twice, as you expected.  Now, the code is horrid — absolutely horrid.  If you compiled with -Werror=shadow you'd get errors about the redefinition of x shadowing the variable defined at global scope.  But that would be better than trying to mess with nested scopes like that.  But I think the compilers are both wrong, technically, though they are differently wrong. [continued 2…]

[…continuation 2…] As I said, I don't like my conclusions — disagreeing with the compilers is not healthy. But sometimes the compilers make mistakes — not often, but they do. And when two compilers produce different results and it is not "implementation-defined" behaviour, there are problems. And abhorrent code like the code in the question should be discouraged.  I think GCC's behaviour is less erroneous than Clang's behaviour; it doesn't compile the dubious code, whereas Clang produces erroneous output without diagnosing the dubious code.  But degrees of erroneousness are not comfortable.

@JonathanLeffler: x in static int x = 10; has no linkage. If it were at file scope, it would have internal linkage, per C 2018 6.2.2 3: “If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier static, the identifier has internal linkage.” But it is at block scope, so it has no linkage, per 6.2.2 6: “The following identifiers have no linkage: an identifier declared to be anything other than an object or a function; … function parameter; a block scope identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier extern.”

Both GCC and Clang conform to the C standard in regard to this situation because the behavior is not defined by the C standard.
static int x = 50; appears at file scope and gives its x internal linkage per C 2018 6.2.2 3:

If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier static, the identifier has internal linkage.

static int x = 10; appears at block scope and gives its x no linkage per 6.2.2 6:

The following identifiers have no linkage: …; a block scope identifier for an object declared without the storage-class specifier extern.

Where extern int x; appears, the second x is visible, so 6.2.2 4 applies:

For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration. If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

Since the visible prior declaration of x has no linkage, the last sentence above tells us this third x has external linkage. (Note that the first x is not visible because the second x hides it.)
Now we have an x that appears three times: First with internal linkage, then with no linkage, then with external linkage. Then 6.2.2 7 applies:

If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

Since the C standard does not define the behavior, it is conforming for GCC to produce a diagnostic and/or to reject the code, and it is conforming for Clang not to produce a diagnostic and to accept the code.

You mentioned: "Where extern int x; appears, the second x is visible" In question #67418392 you mentioned "Where extern int x; appears, it declares a third x that hides the previous x" I am curious if the result of the extern statement being classified as external linkage is the result of the previous x (in the main function) having no linkage and being visible to the extern statement or the result of the previous x (in the main function) being invisible to the extern statement since it shadows it and therefore the extern statement is classified as external linkage?

[...continuation...] Or perhaps there is no contradiction between your two statements? When the extern statement is being evaluated in the C abstract machine the second x is visible and the rules of 6.2.2 4 is applied and then once the rules are applied the x in the extern statement now hides the second x in the main function?

@vanfifty: In both this question and that, the second declaration hides the first, and, at the third declaration, the second declaration is visible and the first is not. In both cases, the second declaration has no linkage, and the third has external linkage. There is no contradiction. The difference is that, in this question, the first declaration has internal linkage (because it uses static), and, in the other declaration, the third has external linkage. In this question, the different linkages mean the behavior is undefined. In the other question, the same linkages do not cause a problem.

Thank you for clarifying. I initially thought you may have been implying that in the other question the second declaration is not visible however now I understand as you mentioned that it is visible in both questions at the third declaration. After the third declaration in the other question it hides the second declaration and in this question we have undefined behaviour after the third declaration.

The error occurs in GCC because it doesn't allow redeclaring a static variable (with internal linkage) as extern (which assumes external linkage). Clang and MSVC, however, handle this situation by allowing the extern declaration to refer to the file-scope variable, treating it with internal linkage. This difference results in GCC throwing an error, while Clang and MSVC produce the expected output.

Is the code valid according to the standard or not?  If it is invalid, then throwing an error is correct (and not throwing an error is incorrect).  If it is valid, then throwing an error is incorrect.  And if the code is valid, is the behaviour of printing 50 correct?  It seems to me that it is completely incorrect.  If the inner scope were deleted, the "outer block" should print the value 10, not 50.  (See also my triple comment to the question.)

@JonathanLeffler: Since your definition of “invalid” apparently is or includes that  the compiler must “throw” an “error,” by which I presume you mean issue a diagnostic message or reject the code or both, the code is valid because the C standard does not require implementations to diagnose or reject it. Per my answer, both compilers conform because the C standard does not specify what the behavior is.
